# Proper implementation of producer-consumer scenario and "graceful" termination of thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I am working on my first multi-threaded project and thus have a couple of things that I am unsure of. Details on my setup was on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943430/parallel-processing-in-java-advice-needed-i-e-on-runnanble-callable-interfaces), in short: I have a thread pool implemented by `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N)`. One thread is given an action which does a series of queries to local and remote resources and iteratively populates an `ArrayBlockingQueue`, while the rest of the threads invoke `take()` method on the queue and process the objects in the queue.

Even though small and supervised tests seem to run OK, I am unsure about how I handle special scenarios such as the beginning (the queue has no items yet), the end (the queue is emptied), and any eventual `InterruptedExceptions`. I have done some reading here on SO, which then led me to two really nice articles by [Goetz](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236.html) and [Kabutz](http://www.javaspecialists.co.za/archive/Issue056.html). The consensus seems to be that one should not ignore these exceptions. However I am unsure how the examples supplied relates to my situation, I have not invoked `thread.interrupt()` anywhere in my code... Speaking of which, I'm getting unsure if I should have done so...

To sum it up, given the code below, how do I best handle the special cases, such as termination criteria and the InterrruptedExceptions? Hope the questions make sense, otherwise I'll do my best to describe it further.

Thanks in advance,

---

**edit:** I have been working on the implementation for a while now, and I have come across a new hiccup so I figured I'd update the situation. I have had the misfortune of coming across `ConcurrentModificationException` which was most likely due to incomplete shutdown/termination of the thread pool. As soon as I figured out I could use `isTerminated()` I tried that, then I got a `IllegalMonitorStateException` due to an unsynchronized `wait()`. The current state of the code is below:

I have followed some of the advices from @Jonathan's answer, however I don't think his proposal works quite like what I need/want. The background story is the same as I have mentioned above, and relevant bits of code are as follows:

Class holding/managing the pool, and submission of runnables:

```
public void serve() {
    try {
        this.started = true;
        pool.execute(new QueryingAction(pcqs));
        for(;;){
            PathwayImpl p = bq.take();

            if (p.getId().equals("0")){
                System.out.println("--DEBUG: Termination criteria found, shutdown initiated..");
                pool.shutdown();
                            // give 3 minutes per item in queue to finish up
                pool.awaitTermination(3 * bq.size(), TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                break;
            }
            int sortMethod = AnalysisParameters.getInstance().getSort_method();
            pool.submit(new AnalysisAction(p)); 
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
          System.err.println("Unexpected error in core analysis, terminating execution!");
          System.exit(0);
      }finally{   pool.shutdown();     }
}

public boolean isDone(){
    if(this.started)
        return pool.isTerminated();
    else
        return false;
    }
```

---

Elements are added to the queue by the following code on located in a separate class:

```
this.queue.offer(path, offer_wait, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

... motivation behind `offer()` instead of `take()` is as Jonathan mentioned. Unforeseen blocks are annoying and hard to figure out as my analysis take a long time as it is. So I need to know relatively quick if the fails due to a bad block, or if it's just crunching numbers...

---

and finally; here's the code in my test class where I check the interaction between the "concurrency service" (named cs here) and the rest of the objects to be analyzed:

```
cs.serve();
synchronized (this) {
    while(!cs.isDone())
    this.wait(5000);
}
ReportGenerator rg = new ReportGenerator();
rg.doReports();
```

I realize that this has been a VERY long question but I tried to be detailed and specific. Hopefully it won't be too much of a drag, and I apologize in case it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `take`, which blocks, use something more like this:

```
PathwayImpl p = null;
synchronized (bq) {
    try {
        while (bq.isEmpty() && !stopSignal) {
            bq.wait(3000); // Wait up to 3 seconds and check again
        }

        if (!stopSignal) {
            p = bq.poll();
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        // Broke us out of waiting, loop around to test the stopSignal again
    }
}
```

This assumes that the block is enclosed in some sort of `while (!stopSignal) {...}`.

Then, in the code that adds to the queue, do this:

```
synchronized (bq) {
    bq.add(item);
    bq.notify();
}
```

As for `InterruptedException`s, they are good for signaling the thread to test the stop signal immediately, instead of waiting until the next timeout-and-test. I suggest just testing your stop signal again, and possibly logging the exception.

I use them when signaling a panic, versus a normal shutdown, but it is rare that such a situation is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jonathan. Would you care to elaborate on a couple of points tho? First of all why not `take()`, is it better to deal with nulls or with Exceptions? Secondly I don't really follow why you put stuff in a separate synchronized block, as bq should already be a thread-safe collection, am I mistaken? And finally, how do you suggest I go about implementing the stopSignal; as a boolean for instance?

Comment: 1) `take()` will block, requiring you to manually interrupt the thread if you want to let it know that it should check `stopSignal`. 2) The synchronized blocks allow you to use `wait()` and `notify()`. 3) The `stopSignal` would be a boolean instance variable, likely toggled by some kind of `public void requestHalt()` function, or similar.